# Where does the factor $(y^2 + 1)$ come from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I keep looking and writing out the problem, but I don't know where $(y^2 + 1)$ comes from. I get $y^2(y-3)$ as the numerator instead, but I can't tell if I'm having a brain fart and am missing something.

[image]

Comment: If you get $y^2(y-3)$, how can the second term $(y-3)$ of the numerator disappear by magic ?

Comment: What my mistake was, was that I got rid of the $(y - 3)$ in the denominator and got rid of one of the $(y - 3)$ in the numerator. What I should have done was see it as $y^2(y - 3) + 1(y - 3)$ instead. I was in the rhythm in doing other types of these problems where everything in the numerator was all multiplied together, so I needed to just take one out then.

Comment: Yep, I am not surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y^2(y-3)+(y-3)=y^2(y-3)+(1)(y-3)=(y^2+1)(y-3)$$

We just factorize $y-3$ out.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see now! I forgot to get rid of both (y - 3) in the numerator! Thank you!